# How to render the react native code in react app in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, next.js, frontend

If I have an entire website built using React.JS or Next.JS and an app in React Native, instead of writing media queries for my website can I render the app UI along with functionality (basically the entire app), for mobile and tablet viewports?

Note: My doubt is not about code sharing.

*what I expect* :

```
if width>768px
  render Next JS code OR React code
else 
  render React Native code
```

( *all this happens in the browser* )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not possible due to the fact that the `React Js (or Next js)` apps are completely different from each other and they use different environments for rendering contents .
the only way for you  is running both your apps `(React and React Native)` side by side in completely different browser tabs.

Comment: is not there any parser that converts RN to HTML? also in the end both of them are bundles of JS so I am confused

Comment: no ,unfortunately  we don't have a tool for that .